# Why can't i set button position at the same line and tied to each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to align two button to be tie at the same "line" (without any gap in x-axis). For some reason, i can't understand why, button aren't at the same line.
I want to understand what i am doing wrong

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
```

should possibly be

```
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
```

Comment: Now, i understand why the aren't at the same "line" . but : 1. Why is the reason that at the code i have posted button2 top isn't at the same line as button top? it's top is a little bit lower than button bottom. 2.I have changed the code the way you told me, now they are at the same line, but still there is a little gap between both button on x-axis. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: If you set button2's `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"` as well, their tops will also align

Comment: Ok,thanks. but your answer isn't refer to the question i have asked :)

Comment: Do you have an idea?

Comment: Haha oh yeah sorry, maybe it's because of the text you're setting? What is `@string/app_name`? Also if I answered your original question could you please mark my answer as correct? :)

Comment: Please accept my apologize but my original question was not written 100% clear, and I hope someone can help me with that, so I won’t need to post a new one with the same content. About the string, it isn’t long, it’s:”My Application”

Comment: If you want extra information you _should_ ask a new question, in order to help other people with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In button2 constrains should be

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
```

Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Set margin button2  based on your needs. now its in same line.

Comment: Now, i understand why the aren't at the same "line" . but : 1. Why is the reason that at the code i have posted button2 top isn't at the same line as button top? it's top is a little bit lower than button bottom.  2.I have changed the code the way you told me, now they are at the same line, but still there is a little gap between both button on x-axis. Can you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
```

(because this will set your button2's top to bottom of button(1).

from button2 with these

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are aligning your bottom button to end of your first button using this 
  `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"` but you need to start and end your bottom with first like bellow

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button"
```

Full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```